# how to send android RequestHttpURLConnection array

Tags: android, arraylist, httpconnection

I want to send array data to server.

data format is :

```
{
  "email": "test11@test.com",
  "password": "1234",
  "name": "username",
  "job": [
    {
      "id": "12"
    },
    {
      "id": "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my android code :

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("email", param.getEmail());
contentValues.put("password", param.getPassword());
contentValues.put("name", param.getName());

Gson gson = new Gson();
String s = gson.toJson(param.getJob());
contentValues.put("job", s);

(String 's' is  [{"id":"22"},{"id":"28"},{"id":"32"}] )


public class RequestHttpURLConnection {
 
    public String request(String _url, ContentValues _params) {
 
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
        StringBuffer sbParams = new StringBuffer();
 
        if (_params == null)
            sbParams.append("");
        else {
            boolean isAnd = false;
            String key;
            String value;
 
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> parameter : _params.valueSet()) {
                key = parameter.getKey();
                value = parameter.getValue().toString();
 
                if (isAnd)
                    sbParams.append("&");
 
                sbParams.append(key).append("=").append(value);
 
                if (!isAnd)
                    if (_params.size() >= 2)
                        isAnd = true;
            }
        }
 
        try {
            URL url = new URL(_url);
            urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 
            urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConn.setDoInput(true);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8"); // Accept-Charset 설정.
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Context_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream()));
            pw.write(sbParams.toString());
            pw.flush(); 
            pw.close(); 
 
            if (urlConn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                return null;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
 
            String line;
            String page = "";
 
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                page += line;
            }
            return page;
 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) { // for URL.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { // for openConnection().
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConn != null)
                urlConn.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried many methods but all failed.

contentValues.put("job", "[{id:19},{id:25}]");

contentValues.put("job", "{id:19},{id:25}");

contentValues.put("job", "[id=19]");

contentValues.put("job", "{id=19}");

contentValues.put("job", "{id:19}");

contentValues.put("job", "[{id:19}]");

contentValues.put("job", "[{id=19}]");

Server don't respond. 200,403,500, anything.

I don't know how to send array data.
please help me.

Comment: Why not use Retrofit or Volley? Because, these libraries are very useful for HTTP request.

Comment: I didn't know about the library. I will try that. Thank you.